# Is it possible to deploy oracle forms application(.fmb and .fmx) into jBoss AS?

Tags: jboss, weblogic, oracleforms, application-server

I am looking for a solution to migrate oracle forms applications from weblogic AS to jBoss AS. Is it possible? I googled it and went through a number of articles, but did not find a solution.

Any help  would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i reached at a conclusion!

The simple answer is NO.

Oracle forms apps are running using native compiler in fusion middleware AS. So if we want
to deploy the oracle forms into jBoss, we need to write compiler for each oracle forms depending on the app and its complexity.